# Silverlight can not add reference to ruby service

Tags: silverlight, service, methods, reference

My friend made a web service in ruby (http://195.117.148.68:3000/api/wsdl). My job is to work with this service in Silverlight.

I am making new Silverlight project then right click and "Add Service Reference...". Then I am giving address -> Go and everything is fine. However the generated Client do not contain the methods of a web service. The question is why?

I am just starting with those web services. I have made successfully a working example with cross domain WCF Service Application, but with others it does not generate methods.

If any one can help me I will be very grateful. I have spend one day and can't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the generation of the proxy class. If this is the only way you know to create a proxy, then examine the WSDL and see if something is missing from the mix. If all of the methods are set up correctly, you will have to dig deeper.

You could also try the WSDL.exe utility on the command line and see if you are getting any warnings or errors. This could help clue you in on why it is failing.

As a kind of work around, you can create an empty service that adheres to the interface in the Ruby service (same methods, objects, etc.) and create a proxy off that service. You then point to the Ruby address and work through any exceptions. This is a bit of a cheat to avoid creating your own custom proxy objects.

The final method is creating your own proxy objects. The upside is you will likely create a more "efficient" proxy. The downside is having ot write the "plumbing" code yourself, which could be more time consuming.

Comment: There is some warning but is says not much for me. The warning is too long and I can not put answer So I will paste it in following comments:

Comment: Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
R2706: A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST use the value of "literal" for the use attribute in all soapbind:body, soapbind:fault, soapbind:header and soapbind:headerfault elements.

Comment: -  Input element soapbind:body of operation 'GetTests' on portType 'wsdlApiBinding' from namespace 'urn:ActionWebService'.

Comment: -  Output element soapbind:body of operation 'GetTests' on portType 'wsdlApiBinding' from namespace 'urn:ActionWebService'.

Comment: -  Input element soapbind:body of operation 'CheckCorectness' on portType 'wsdlApiBinding' from namespace 'urn:ActionWebService'.

Comment: -  Output element soapbind:body of operation 'CheckCorectness' on portType 'wsdlApiBinding' from namespace 'urn:ActionWebService'.